# Change title background color or making it transparent : android

Tags: android

How can i change bgcolor of title bar. By default white color is assigned to it, due to which battery usage,time & notification icons are not visible.

Check this image link for problem description :

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCxo3.png)

[image]

I have set an image to relative layout :

```
android:background="@drawable/img_bg"
```

And applied NoActionBar theme to the activity

```
<activity 
   android:name=".activity.LoginActivity" 
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
</activity>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Go to styles.xml file
Check  in AppTheme colorPrimaryDark is mention or not .Change that color to  #000000FF for transparent background.

Comment: Tried it.. did not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Change Window  Title bar Color :

```
Window window = activity.getWindow();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.yourColor));
        }
```

for api<21 ,  :

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
        <!-- Customize your theme using Material Design here. -->
        <!-- Title Bar color here -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">#YOUR_COLOR_HERE</item>
        <!-- Background color here -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">#YOUR_COLOR_HERE</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thanks @Shiva it worked :)

Comment: But It will only works for Api level greater than 21 .

Comment: please check the edited answer.

Comment: android:Theme.Material requires API level 21 (current min is 16).. i guess it is for api>21

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (it will only change your title bar color):

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorXYZ</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: tried ..still same